# Regexextract from right not greedy

Tags: regex, google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I need to extract the last occurrence date from the following text :

```
{"date":"2018-07-17","activeTime":10140679}{"date":"2018-07-18","activeTime":5550031}{"date":"2018-07-19","activeTime":6120026}{"date":"2018-07-20","activeTime":3150019}{"date":"2018-07-23","activeTime":5250034}{"date":"2018-07-24","activeTime":3840018}{"date":"2018-07-26","activeTime":5850060}{"date":"2018-07-27","activeTime":8670076}{"date":"2018-07-30","activeTime":870009}{"date":"2018-07-31","activeTime":30000}
```

I'm using the following formula :

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(S2;"date"":""([\d-]+).*}$")
```

It works but

> it extract the first result and not the last.

Do you know how to extract only the last one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a all consuming greedy expression (aka the `.*`) before your actual expression:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(S2;".*date"":""([\d-]+).*}$")
```